# Block Template not Loading

Tags: layout, blocks, template, magento-1

So it's been a day and a half on this. Really need some help!

I cannot get `$this->getChildHtml()` to pull in my template. I have tried heaps but will outline the main things. First, my code:

app/design/frontend/.../template/pvtl/shiptwo/shiptwo-product-view.phtml

```
<p>
    This is the block you are looking for.
</p>
```

app/design/frontend/.../layout/pvtl_shiptwo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="pvtl_shiptwo/shiptwoView" name="view.shiptwo" as="shiptwoProductView"
                   template="pvtl/shiptwo/shiptwo-product-view.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

app/design/frontend/.../template/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
...
<div class="product-view">
<div class="product-essential">
    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
    <div class="no-display">
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value=""/>
    </div>

    <div class="product-img-box">
        <div class="product-name">
            <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
    </div>

    <div class="product-shop">
        <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product, array('_secure' => $this->_isSecure())) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if ($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
            <div class="product-name">
                <span class="h1"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Below should print template contents but doesn't -->
            <div class="shiptwo_product_view">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('shiptwoProductView'); ?>
            </div>
            ...
```

I know the block is being loaded as the name is printed when I use

```
<?php echo "<pre>", print_r($this->getSortedChildren(), 1), "</pre>"; ?>
```

I also tried the following:

```
<?php echo "<pre>", print_r($this->getChild('shiptwoProductView')->getTemplate(), 1), "</pre>"; ?>
```

This returns the correct template path. I have checked this path tens of times. It is correct.

To make sure the block was actually working I created a method inside `Pvtl_Shiptwo_Block_ShiptwoView`:

```
public function showText() {
    return 'Working!';
}
```

and called

```
<?php echo "<pre>", print_r($this->getChild('shiptwoProductView')->showText(), 1), "</pre>"; ?>
```

This returned the correct output.

I am completely stuck on this! Somebody please help!!

**Edit**
By request, here is my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config>
<modules>
    <Pvtl_Shiptwo>
        <version>0.1</version>
    </Pvtl_Shiptwo>
</modules>

<global>
    <blocks>
        <pvtl_shiptwo>
            <class>Pvtl_Shiptwo_Block</class>
        </pvtl_shiptwo>
    </blocks>
</global>

<frontend>
    <routers>
        <pvtl_shiptwo>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Pvtl_Shiptwo</module>
                <frontName>Shiptwo</frontName>
            </args>
        </pvtl_shiptwo>
    </routers>

    <layout>
        <updates>
            <pvtl_shiptwo>
                <file>pvtl_shiptwo.xml</file>
            </pvtl_shiptwo>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
</config>
```

**Edit**

Screenshot of folder structure

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure your custom block extends `Mage_Core_Block_Template` ?

Could show us your custom block file?

Comment: The block extends from `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract`. This is how I have worked it for all of my extensions previously. Should I be using `_Template` instead?

Comment: You can use Mage_Core_Block_Template . Anyway Mage_Core_Block_Template extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is presented in your block naming part.

You should name your block file with first letter capital and then all others small like this:

```
class Pvtl_Shiptwo_Block_Shiptwoview
```

Then in your layout file your code will be:

```
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="pvtl_shiptwo/shiptwoview" name="view.shiptwo" as="shiptwoProductView"
                   template="pvtl/shiptwo/shiptwo-product-view.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this made no difference. I think I'm going to go insane!

Comment: How is your config.xml? Please add to the qst.

Comment: I have added this to the question

Comment: Can you confirm your folder structure is like this: Pvtl->Shiptwo->Block->Shiptwoview.php and you have cleared your cache?

Comment: All that is correct. Will post screenshot

Comment: Can you also confirm that your module is running? You can check this from `System > Configuration > Advance`, you should see your module in that list.

Comment: I have checked this and is definitely running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39705/discussion-between-adarsh-khatri-and-matt1985).